# LU-factorisation of a square matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to show that the following matrix cannot be factor into the product LU.

\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\2&4&0\\ 0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I did the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\2&4&0\\ 0&1&-1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\2&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\0&0&2\\ 0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The matrix cannot be factored into a product LU since $0$ in position (2,2) makes it impossible to eliminate the lower diagonal entry position (3,2).

I read that I need to use pivoting and swaps second and third rows of $A$ but I don't know how to continue. Anyone can  help?

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&-1\\0&1&-1\\ 2&4&0\end{bmatrix} = 
\end{equation}

Comment: I figure out how to solve it. Thanks